# Storing multiple device tokens in one document to query from cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a chat app that pushes notifications when a new message sent in a chat group. Every chat group has their own document in the chat groups collection and each document has a collection called messages inside it. I use cloud functions to listen to the changes in the messages collection. When a user adds a new document, I need to query the user documents of all members in a chat group except the sender to get the device tokens, so I can push notifications. However, repeating this process every time someone sends a message leads to an incredible amount of reads. The number of messages might easily climb into thousands even for a small chat app and so the reads.

In order to save money, I decided to create documents to store multiple user tokens in the same document up to 1000 users. I limited it to 1000 due to the size limit for a single document, but I put the device tokens of the users who are related to each other in the same document because they are probably in the same chat groups. I'm expecting a huge decrease on reads because I can query only one or two documents to get all user tokens in a big chat group instead of querying one document for one token. Although everything sounds good here, I can't beat my worries. I would like to hear your precious opinions. Is this an efficient workaround? What are the possible problems here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing multiple pieces of content in a single document is an effective way to reduce the number of document reads. You seem to already be taking some considerations into account, but here are a few more:

- You won't be able to effectively query the tokens in the single document, so will have to rely on another way of finding the documents you need. You're already grouping them in some way, but this is something to keep in mind.
- You'll typically end up storing each token in multiple documents. If you've never done this before, it may feel a bit uncomfortable, but it's normal when dealing with NoSQL databases. You would end with multiple writes for a token though: one for each aggregated document that it needs to be in.
- Since you can only read complete documents, you will always be reading all tokens. If there are cases where you need a subset of the tokens in your aggregated documents, you'll be wasting bandwidth.
- You could consider using the Firebase Realtime Database for storing the tokens, which doesn't have the concept of document reads, and only charges for the storage and bandwidth used by the tokens (in JSON).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I'd like to explain the way that I found to query the right document in which the token I need stored if anyone wonders. I give names to the those token documents. When I create a chat group document, I include member ids as keys along with the name of the token document that contains their tokens as values in a map, so I can know which user token is in which token document when I get to query.